# .Net Core Worker Service as a windows service does not work sometimes

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-core-service-worker

I created a worker service within a .Net Core API and running this API on a windows server. I'm hosting this worker service as a windows service in that windows server. This works most of the time, but sometimes, the windows service seems to be running but no code written within worker service is executed. What could be the cause and how to fix it?

Code in Worker Service looks at records in a database table and performs some operations.

Comment: Hi @DevInspirer, Without any of the code and error message, it is hard to narrow down the problem. I suggest you could try to use Try-Catch statement and Logging in your worker service, and check if there have some exception, you could refer the following links: [Logging in .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0) and [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio).

Comment: Thrown exceptions in the worker service will not shut down your windows service.  Your service will still run but the woker service doesn't.

Comment: Thanks! I was enclosing try catch block outside the while loop in worker service class. So, whenever there was an exception, it came out of loop to catch the exception and it never worked. enclosing try-catch within while loop fixed the issue. Thanks for the help.